# Never+would have

Tags: sentence-meaning

***Chuck never in a million years would've given to Jimmy.***
(from Better Call Saul which is tv series)

What is the meaning of this sentence ?

1-He didn't give but he would.

2-He didn't give and he wouldn't.

3-He did give but he wouldn't.

4-He did give and he would.

I am confused with the "negative would have forms" . Is it imagine situation in the past (=that didnt happen) like "would have done" forms ?

About context : Jimmy's brother(Chuck) died and gave nothing to Jimmy but Chuck's friend is trying to give something to Jimmy and someone in the room says :"Chuck never in a million years would've given to Jimmy." . I think the answer is obviously 2 but how could we know the correct answer if there were no background informations ?

Comment: Could you please tell us the source of that sentence? Also, please describe the context in which it was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a particular meaning of this sentence that is lost without some background information, however a general answer can still be given.

To start, let's eliminate some of the extraneous information to simplify the sentence:

> He never would have done it.

Such a sentence is grammatical on its own, but it lacks reference to understand its actual meaning. There are two broader contexts in which it could fit:

> A: (Unlike some other people), *he* never would have done it.

Here, he wouldn't have done it and, unlike somebody else who did (I am inferring), he *didn't* do it.

This equates to your second option.

But we can also look at the sentence in this way:

> B1: He never would have done it (*had it not been for what happened*).
>   B2: He never *would* have done it. (*But then the unthinkable happened.*)

Here, it's saying that he never would have done it—*up until* something occurred when things changed, resulting in him doing it after all.

This roughly equates to your third option, except that it needs to be rephrased:

> He did give but he wouldn't *have until then*.

---

So, returning to your actual question, unless we have more context from the *Better Call Saul* episode, it's impossible to say if Chuck actually *did* give something to Jimmy or not.